# When in making register service in android programming

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to make a login, and register system using Android Studio, and PHP.
However, I have a problem in making a new member.
The following are source codes regarding registry service.

```html
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ekb2011", "*********", "ekb2011");
 $userID=$_POST["postID"];
 $userPassword=$_POST["userPassword"];
 $userName=$_POST["userName"];
 
 $statement=mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO USER VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $userID, $userPassword, $userName);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
 
 $response=array();
 $response["success"]=true;

 echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

And the following is a source code from Android Studio connecting with PHP.

```
enter code here
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    final static private String URL="http://ekb2011.cafe24.com/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    public RegisterRequest(String userID, String userPassword, String userName, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, URL, listener, null);
        parameters=new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("userID", userID);
        parameters.put("userPassword", userPassword);
        parameters.put("userName", userName);
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams(){
        return parameters;
    }

}
```

When I register a new member, userID, userPassword, and userName don't appear on the database.
How can I fix these code to run?

Comment: what error you facing while running this code ? tell more about the error coming in DB also.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps the problem is:

```
$userID=$_POST["postID"];
```

it should be:

```
$userID=$_POST["userID"];
```

and it's better to include column names and check if query executed as well somehow like this:

```
<?php
$response=array();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ekb2011", "*********", "ekb2011");
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response["error"] = "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die(json_encode($response));
}


$userID=$_POST["userID"];
$userPassword=$_POST["userPassword"];
$userName=$_POST["userName"];

$statement=mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO USER (columnId, colunPassword, columnUsername) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");// Change columnId, colunPassword, columnUsername with your table column names
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $userID, $userPassword, $userName);


if(mysqli_stmt_execute($statement)){

    $response["success"]=true;
}else{
    $response["success"]=false;
    $response["error"]=mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Can I ask why userID, userPassword, userName may be changed into columnID, columnPassword, columnName?

Comment: columnID, columnPassword and columnUsername are your column names in your table, i didn't know what are their name in your table so i told to change them with your column names.

Comment: and sql insert query is like: "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)"